# :before pseudo-element causes gap in border

Tags: css, border

I have this piece of HTML that I want to style.
The html is a table (and actual table), which I want to give a border.
The element also had a :before pseudo-element, which I use to put a small triangle in the top corner.

The JSFiddle is here.
I hope it makes sense. I stripped down the markup and the CSS as much as possible, because it's actually a small part of a big site.

http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/28yDb/2/

Now the problem is that the combination of having 2 columns, having `border-collapse: collapse;` on the table and the `:before` pseudo element, cause the top border of the element to partially disappear. It's only there for the length of the first column.

You would assume that it is the pseudo element that is on top of the border, but this element is very small, and as far as I can tell, this could not be the problem. I added `visibility: hidden;` to the pseudo element to be sure, and I can tell that the triangle is gone, but the border is still incomplete.

Unfortunately I cannot change the markup, since this is outputted by MediaWiki, but I do have full control over the CSS.

The HTML:

```
<div id="globalWrapper">
<div id="column-content">
<div class="thumb tright">
<table class="infobox vcard" style="">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" class="fn org" style=""> Example text</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Row head</th>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
```

The CSS:

```
/* Generic table styling */
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /*border-spacing: 0;*/ }

/* The box */
.thumb.tright table.infobox.vcard {
    border: 3px solid #fae104;
    position: relative;
}

/* Triangle */
  .thumb.tright table.infobox.vcard:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 1px;
    border-top: 5px solid transparent;
    top: -7px;
    border-left: 10px solid #555;
    visibility: hidden;
    right: -1px; }
```

I already found out that it works when I remove `border-collapse: collapse;`, but I'm not sure that is a proper solution, and even if it is, I would really like an explanation of what is going on.

Btw. I got this problem both in Chrome 29 and in Internet Explorer 10. Haven't tested other browsers.

### Update

Instead of using -or *not* using- 'border-collapse' to fix the problem, I found out that this also works:

```
.thumb.tright table.infobox.vcard tbody {
    display: block;
}
```

So the table itself is still a table, the pseudo element is still on the table, as is the border, positioning etc. The tbody, which was unstyled before, is now a block and the problem is solved in both browsers. I found this by trial and error, and still wouldn't know the reason behind it.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/28yDb/9/

Comment: That's really weird behavior.

Comment: dont use tables where they not needed its bad stuff

Comment: @Prozi Like I said, I don't control how the HTML is generated. Besides, this table will contain tabular data, so the use of tables is fair in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being a newbie to StackOverflow *and* jsFiddle I [updated the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/28yDb/12/) with that I think is the solution. I didn't change the CSS except for moving the pseudo class from the table itself to the table header, and changing it into :after. Works for me in Firefox and Chrome!

```
/* Triangle */ 
.thumb.tright table.infobox.vcard th:after { }
```

Border-collapse: seperate is not supported in IE8 but I think this will be.

- edit: nevermind ;)

Comment: Any reason you used `:after` instead of `:before`? Both seem to work fine. I like your solution by the way. I think you are right by moving the pseudo-element to the `th`, because the pseudo-element actually just adds content, which the `th` can contain, while the table itself cannot. This might be the actual cause, although it is very odd that both Chrome and IE show the same 'unpredictable' result. I bet Google nicked Microsoft's code again. ;)

Comment: I'll leave it to smarter people to explain the exact 'why' it didn't work before ;) 
I used the :after just because it felt more natural to me to create the pseudo element after the table header. Because the arrow thingy was supposed to go to the top right. But as you already pointed out, it doesn't really matter which of the two you use.

Comment: I think this may be in the direction of the official answer you're looking for - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#border-conflict-resolution the W3 Tables Spec on "Border conflict resolution". I think the pseudo-element, when applied to the table, overrides the table border around the top right cell, resulting in the disappearance of the original yellow border.

Comment: That seems to be it. Thank you very much for clearing this up!

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem only occur on Webkit browsers I think. It can be considered a "browser bug" imo.

th should be inside thead, not tbody:

```
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" class="fn org" style=""> Example text</th>
        </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Row head</th>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
<tbody>
```

And I think this is the correct solution. You are putting an element where it is not advised to be, so it should be normal for a problem to occur.

**Edit**: as thirtydot pointed out, changing the th to td doesn't change the result. It only work when I moved the th to the thead section. At this point I am at a loss, I can't find a way to solve this.

But at least I think I can provide my speculation on the cause of this problem:
:before create a pseudo element inside the target element. What kind of element is unknown to me, but I suspect that the browser create a td. If that is true, then after rendering your html should look like this:

```
<table>
       <td></td> /*the pseudo element*/
       <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2" class="fn org" style=""> Example text</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Row head</th>
                    <td>Content</td>
                </tr>
        <tbody>
</table>
```

Needless to say this look weird. And if you try the above html out you can see the result is similar to your problem. border-collapse:collapse will merge 2 borders together where there are 2 cells next to each other, or a cell is next to the table's border. So I suspect in this case, the pseudo element - which doesn't have appropriate colspan - last only 1 column, the rest of that row is empty: nothing's there. This is where I think caused the bug: because there's no cells next to the table border there, no border is created at all.

The real reason may be a little bit more complicated ("why doesn't the bug occur when I put in a thead?"), but I think my answer is not too far off the mark. :)

Comment: Same problem happens with `td`s instead of `th`s: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/28yDb/4/

Comment: Thanks, I totally overlooked it. I updated my answer, but now it's no longer an answer I think :)

Comment: I doubt it's a browser bug. I got it in IE 10 as well, and I don't think that is a webkit browser. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The only reasonable explanation I can think of is `pseudo-element :before` not being compatible with the `display: table` of the `table` in `collapsed` mode. That is why `border-collapse: separate;` solves the problem. Suddenly, the browser can display the top border not caring about the pseudo element.

If you look closely, you can clearly see that the missing part of the border is the width of the second column. If you change it to `after` pseudo element, the border is missing in the bottom-right corner, again due to the fact that the borders of the table and the pseudo-element are collapsed.

If you change the `border-bottom` of `th` to be `3px solid red` in `collapsed` mode, the `th` overpowers the `table` and the border is red. I presume, the power of `after` and `before` follow the same rule. It would be nice if someone who knows the specs better came to answer that.

Thinking this way, I do not believe there can be any other solution than:

- using separate borders
- putting the pseudo element on the parent `div`

---

What I inspected is that the `pseudo element` is actually rendered as `block` and can be change to `table` and `list-item`. However, none of these change the behaviour.

---

**Very random stuff** that is actually compliant with Av Avt's answer about where the pseudo element is rendered in regards of the DOM.

If I append the `:beofre` like this, the border stays:

```
.thumb.tright table.infobox.vcard tr:before
```

Obviously, it creates as many new pseudo element as there are rows.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed (and even mentioned) that the border only spans the first column. And that's why I especially think it is odd. After all, the top row in the table only has one column, so if the border-top would collapse or disappear, I would expect it to disappear entirely, not partially. Your remark about incompatibility makes sense, but since this occurs in both Chrome and IE, it almost seems as 'by design'. I will try your solution adding the `:before` to a tr. This is possible, since in practise, the top row has a different class (lucky me :))

Comment: I tried that, and for some reason the hole in the border moved to the right border instead of the top border. No solution, unfortunately. I did find another work-around that does seem to work, though. See my updated question.

Comment: That is very nice, Kudos :)